# Why do I get Value error when building Linear Regression model?

Tags: python-3.x, linear-regression

I'm trying to build a Linear Regression model for a dataset. After splitting the data into train and test, I get the below error:

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '?'
Does that mean, there is null value or a float value in the dataset?

As I'm new to Python, I don't understand how to rectify this.  Could anyone help me on this?

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import linear_model
df = pd.read_csv('https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/breast-cancer-wisconsin/breast-cancer-wisconsin.data', names = ['ID Number', 'Clump Thickness', 'Uniformity of Cell Size', 'Uniformity of Cell Shape', 'Marginal Adhesion', 'Single Epithelial Cell Size', 'Bare Nuclei', 'Bland Chromatin', 'Normal Nucleoli', 'Mitoses', 'Class'])
X = df.iloc[:, 0:9].values
y = df.iloc[:, 10].values
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.4, random_state = 4)
print(X_train.shape)
print(y_train.shape)
print(X_test.shape)
print(y_test.shape)
lr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
lr.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: Looks like one of the column is of type `object`. Type `X.dtype` and check datatype of each column in your data.

Comment: Yes, one column is of datatype 'Object'. I got the output after deleting that column.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The breast-cancer-wisconsin.data Dataset that you are using has some rows with '?' as  value in 7th column. 
So when you create X and y don't consider the rows with '?' as value.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes. I removed the column and then did the analysis again, got the output.          
Thanks